# xsl:output media-type with the command-line

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

When I use the following in my XSLT file, Saxon outputs the file with a .htm extension

```
<xsl:output method="html"
        version="5.0"
        doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes"
        media-type="text/html"/>
```

However when I run the transformation through the CLI and pass the the output argument using !media-type=text/html Saxon outputs the file with an xml extension

Below is the command I use, am I doing something wrong?

```
java  -jar /Users/Stephane/XSLT_DEV/saxon/saxon9he.jar -s:/Users/Stephane/XSLT_DEV/S1000D/xml/ -o:/Users/Stephane/XSLT_DEV/S1000D/html/ -xsl:$file cssPath='../xslt/assets' imagesPath='graphics/' !method='html' !version='5.0' !encoding='UTF-8' !indent='yes' !media-type='text/html';
```

Comment: I guess CLI = Command Line Interface, not Common Language Infrastructure. You had me confused for a while.

Comment: @MichaelKay Indeed please accept my apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic generation of an output file name occurs only in one specific case: where you use the command line to process an directory of input files to generate a directory of output files. It makes the decision based on the value of `xsl:output/@media-type`, ignoring any value for !media-type supplied on the command line. No particular reason, but that's what it does. The value will be ".xml", ".html", or ".txt".

In all other cases, the output file name is exactly what you choose it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , what I am trying to do is to not use the <xsl:output> element as I need to save the file as XML (For QA purposes) as well as HTML (visual). I am running a build process in Sublime Text. When I remove the <xsl:output> element from my transform file and use the !media-type through the command line Saxon saves the file with a .xml extension not .html

Comment: Sorry about that, but that's the way it works. You could always have a dummy top-level module that contains just an xsl:output and an xsl:import.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think about doing this as I already had a top domain file  with imports. I am going to change my files architecture to do that.